# Creating new column using nvl

Tags: sql, oracle

here is my problem. I have an inner query that is working fine, however when I pass the results to outer query I get an error. What I want to accomplish is this, on the outer query, I want to always check if this column (GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE ) has a value, if it has a value I want to alias it as psi score new column name, additionally if this column does not have a value, I want to check for the second column (PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) if it has a value  I want to alias it as PSI Score (new column). anyone want to take stab at this, I will appreciate it.

```
SELECT
NVL ((CASE WHEN BB.GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE IS NOT NULL THEN BB.GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, ) BB.PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) as PSI SCORE
else null
end



FROM(

SELECT
PARENT_PI_NUMBER,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT,Contest_number,
MAX(AA.GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY AA.ARANK) MAX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,
MAX(AA.PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY AA.ARANK) MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE
FROM (
select  
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENT_PI_NUMBER ORDER BY REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT) ARANK
  ,Contest_number,PARENT_PI_NUMBER,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,PI_NUMBER,PSI_OVERALL_SCORE,GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT
from  
   WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F

WHERE GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE != '10100'
--WHERE PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = '4639022'and GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE is not null
) AA
GROUP BY PARENT_PI_NUMBER,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT,Contest_number;
--ORDER By PARENT_PI_NUMBER,PI_NUMBER,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT;


) BB;
```

Comment: "I get an error" is not very helpful. The actual error you get, along with sample data and expected results would be more helpful. Your code has multiple syntax errors though, build it up a bit at a time from something you know works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your inner query still has a semicolon at the end.
- `MX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE` is 31 characters so isn't valid unless you're on 12cR2 (or higher) with long identifiers enabled.
- Your nvl/case construction has parentheses and `end` in the wrong places and has a spare comma with nothing following it.
- Your nvl/case are attempting to refer to the original `GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE` and `PSI_OVERALL_SCORE` columns, but those are not exposed by the inline view.

It sounds like you're trying to get:

```
COALESCE(BB.MX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, BB.MX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) as PSI_SCORE
```

using the aliases from the inner query, which I've modified from `MAX_` to `MX_` to make the first one legal.

It's hard to tell if the inner query is actually right with data and expected results, but you said that it's doing what you want.

Comment: do I need a case statement before this (COALESCE(BB.MX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, BB.MX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) as PSI_SCORE)?

Comment: @JKim - did you try it? No, you don't - at least, based on your description.

Comment: SELECT  
COALESCE(BB.GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, BB.PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) as PSI_SCORE

FROM(

Comment: Yeah, but like I said already, you need to use the column names from the subquery - i.e. the aliases you're applying to the `max()` clauses

Comment: Thanks very much, you really saved the day. your solution worked.

Comment: one more question please, it appears that the result set is returning multiple rows when I only expect a single row. any suggestion?

Comment: @JKim - your inner query is grouping by four columns, so you'll get one row for each unique combination of those four. Your outer query will see all of those. No idea what you're trying to do with the outer query though - whether you want to see the overall highest score, or the highest per context, or per candidate, or whatever. Maybe you need to include other columns and a group-by in the outer query two. You need to decide based on the output you want.

Comment: I needed to see only the highest score per parent candidate

Comment: So you need to select and group by that column.

Comment: SELECT PARENT_PI_NUMBER,
COALESCE(MAX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) AS PSI_SCORE is what I have on outer query

Comment: grouped it by PARENT_PI_NUMBER but still getting multiple rows

Comment: You should probably ask a new question giving your current query, the table DDL, sample data, and expected results. You probably don't even need the nested queries but it's hard to tell what you are doing and what you need.

Comment: I have posted another question.